# Sudden errors in Resources.java, Context.java and other android utility classes

Tags: java, android, resources, symbols, resolve

I'm trying to work on a new project in Android Studio, and it's a NEW project because every time I try to run any app, at some point, the app will crash, and the debugger will show that there are "symbols" that it cannot resolve or find origins of in utility classes such as Resources and Context and BaseBundle (I don't even know what this class does) and oh so many more.

I'm trying to get extra content from and Intent

```
Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
```

And here's when it crashes. At the `get("data")`

`Build --> Clean Project` and `Build --> Rebuild Project` didn't help.

`File --> Invalidate Caches` didn't help...

Starting a new project didn't help either...

Please Help

Comment: and what if your extras bundle does not have data? maybe that is the problem? I suggest you post more code...

Comment: As above, post the code where the crash is occuring, and post the full stack trace so we can see what the actual error is.

Answer (score 0):

OP here, solved it!
This code initially worked when I tried to get an extra from the camera, and so I figured it would also work if I try to load a picture from the gallery.
Thing is, when you load something from your internal memory, it returns as a URI, which you need to convert to a Bitmap (In case you chose a photo).

the way to do it is as follows:

```
ImageView window = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Uri imageUri = data.getData();
try {
     Bitmap photo = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
     window.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }
catch(Exception e) { System.out.println(e.toString()); }
```

So apparently everytime the utility files get corrupt, it's because I'm doing something that can't be done, as in this case, it couldn't cast `(Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("***")`, and for obvious reasons.
Trouble is, it doesn't really tell you what the problem is, you need to Sherlock Holmes that SoB yourself.